# OpenCV: isOpened() always fails

Tags: c++, opencv

I am taking my first steps with OpenCV and I am trying to run this piece of code. It is supposed to open the specified video in a new window and wait for the user to press ESC. I tried passing both the relative and absolute path to VideoCapture but VideoCapture::isOpened() always fails. Why is this happening?

If I pass 0 to VideoCapture and do NOT call isOpened(), then I get a nice little window.

Note that I am using VS15 and OpenCV 2.4 (with the x86 libs)

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**)
{
   VideoCapture cap(path_to_video); // open the video file
   // VideoCapture cap(0);

   if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
       return -1;

   namedWindow("Video",1);

   for(;;)
   {
       Mat frame;
       cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera        
       imshow("Video", frame);
       if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I solved this by reinstalling OpenCV and creating a new Visual Studio project. The above code miraculously started working.

Comment: Maybe your path is wrong. Have you properly escaped \ ? Did you use the correct extension? Windows explorer hides known extensions by default however in code you must use the extension.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes, I think I have. I used this "C:\\Users\\me\\myproject\\data\\sample.avi".

Comment: can you upload sample.avi or tell us which kind of codec is used? Does your program have access to opencv_ffmpeg*.dll file? Please make sure that it is located in a place where your application can find it (e.g. at the same place where your opencv_core*.dll is present).

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Voting to close this question.

Comment: I agree that this question should be closed. I suspect there is something wrong with my OpenCV installation and/or the Visual Studio project that I set up to run the code. I will delete everything and reinstall them from scratch. Thanks for all your help. EDIT: @MFisherKDX Your comment below was helpful and I tried upvoting it by I couldn't because of my low rating. I do appreciate your input though.

Answer (score -1):

> If I pass 0 to VideoCapture and do NOT call isOpened(), then I get a
>   nice little window. Why is this happening?

Because the `VideoCapture` class has two different constructors. The one that takes a `string` attempts to read from a file. The one that takes an integer attempts to read from a device.  Passing 0 to the second version specifies the default device / camera.

> VideoCapture::open¶  Open video file or a capturing device for video
>   capturing
>
> C++: bool VideoCapture::open(const string& filename)
>   C++: bool VideoCapture::open(int device)
>
> Parameters:
>   filename – name of the opened video file (eg. video.avi)
>   or image sequence (eg. img_%02d.jpg, which will read samples like
>   img_00.jpg, img_01.jpg, img_02.jpg, ...)
>
> device – id of the opened video capturing device (i.e. a camera index).

Comment: The comment "Why is this happening?" was meant for the issue with the video file, as in, why can't I load the video file? :-p I also tried open() but it fails too.